# Retrieve collection of certain firebase document in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

the document name is the auth user but i cant retrive it as index in the firestore i only need to point at the user.uid and retrieve its collection

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Attendees").snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    return new Row( 
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: Text(ds['absenceDay'])),
                        Expanded(child: Text(ds['excuse'])),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        )
```

[image]

Comment: what is the issue? In your code you are retrieving what is inside the collection, what do you what exactly?

Comment: i want the index to point at only 1 collection this code retrieve all the documents inside i only need to retrieve 1 document thats hold the uid name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  getDocument() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     return Firestore.instance.collection("Attendees").document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
```

Then use it in `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: getDocument(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

Comment: no problem, goodluck check my article for later https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/